# Azure IOT Hub data export

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

Do IOT hub retains telemetry data. If yes for how long and how can we access that data in Azure portal? Can we export the telemetry data from IOT hub to excel ?

Answer (score 1):

> how can we access that data in Azure portal? Can we export the telemetry data from IOT hub to excel ?

This is quite a broad question and there are many ways to consume the messages in IoT Hub, but you cannot see it in the Portal and there is no built in way to export the data to Excel.

The closest official solution to Excel export I know is [Set up continuous data export from Azure IoT Central to a Power BI app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/continuously-export-data-from-iot-central-power-bi/).

> Do we have to route it storage unit to view data or IOT hub let us view those data

For an example how to route messages to blob storage please see [Exercise - Create a message route to Azure blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/data-anomaly-detection-using-azure-iot-hub/6-exercise-create-iot-stream-analytics-job) which is part of [Identify anomalies by routing data via IoT Hub to a built-in ML model in Azure Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/data-anomaly-detection-using-azure-iot-hub/) module from [Securely connect IoT devices to the cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/securely-connect-iot-devices/).

> Do IOT hub retains telemetry data. If yes for how long

The standard retention period is 1 day but can be extended to [7 days](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-read-builtin).

---

BTW. If you wish to monitor events as they come in, for testing, you could use Azure CLI's `az iot hub monitor-events` command.

```
az extension add --name azure-iot
az iot hub monitor-events -n <IoT-Hub-Name>
```

Answer (score 0):

IoT Hub exposes device to end users through an [`event hubs endpoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-read-builtin). Event Hubs has a retention time expressed in days. With IoT Hub the related retention time is [`24 hours`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-faq#what-is-the-maximum-retention-period-for-events) by default but you can change it.

Comment: Can we view telemetry data in IOT hub in 24 hours ? I looked in portal, I see metrics showing telemetry received but I don't see way to see actual JSON data received. Do we have to route it storage unit to view data or IOT hub let us view those data in portal ? If we can view telemetry data in portal, I would like to know the way to view that data.

Comment: Usually IOT hub stores the messages in the storage account you configured. you can open storage explorer and see those messages

Comment: I see storage account associated with my subscription. I don't see any storage associated to IOT hub from storage explorer. Any other route to check Storage associated with IOT hub ?

Comment: You can use message routing to route them to storage account https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c